# Google column chart bars width

Tags: angularjs, google-visualization, column-chart

I've got angular2 and google charts.

My component code is:

```
playstoreRatingChart(data) {
        let dateTitle: any = 'Date';
        let ratingTitle: any = 'Rating';
        let dataTable = [[dateTitle, ratingTitle,  { "role": 'annotation' }, { role: 'style' }]];

        data.playstore_rating.forEach(function (obj) {
            let newDate = new Date(obj.year, obj.month-1, obj.day)
            let rating = obj.rating;
            let rowRating = Number(rating.toFixed(2));
            let test = parseFloat(rating.toFixed(2));
            let row = [newDate, test, test, 'width:22; stroke-color: #871B47; stroke-opacity: 0.6; stroke-width: 12; fill-color: #BC5679; fill-opacity: 0.2'];
            dataTable.push(row)
        });

        this.testPlayStore = {
            chartType: 'ColumnChart',
            dataTable: dataTable,
            bar: { groupWidth: '100%' }
        }
    }
```

I don't know, why, but exactly this chart (i have few charts more on this page) have columns with 1px width and I cannot change its width.

Comment: and you've tried changing `bar.groupWidth`?

Comment: You probably have two or more date values that are very close to each other, if not on top of each other.  This would give 0 space between adjacent values, so you are lucky to get 1 pixel.  Perhaps you really want to treat each date as a discrete value rather than a date, which would ignore how close they are to each other.  If so, then convert the date to a string instead.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I've found my data was wrong. Just fixed it and all is ok